# How to display a div in the same line as other divs in the header page

Tags: html, css

I want to display the 3rd div in my header section to the right side of the page and on the same line as the remaining 2 divs.

1st div- Logo

2nd div - SearchBox

3rd div - Login/Register

The 1st two div's are inline but the 3rd div is aligned towards the top margin of the page.

[image]

I tried the following CSS

```
body{
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
}

.logo{
    margin-right: 150px;
    float: left;
}

.anonymous-customer-header{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#search{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">
            <h1>Easy Grocers</h1>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="search">
        <form method="GET" action="/search">
            <input type="search" class="search" name="q" value="" />
            <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="go" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="anonymous-customer-header">
        <a href="/">
            <span>Login</span>
        </a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="/">
            <span>Register</span>
        </a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;

        <span class="cart_items">
            <span class="cart_items_count"><img src="/"/> 0</span>
            <span class="cart_items_countWord">Items</span>
        </span>                
    </div>
</header>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Sai_Upadhyayula/aucex9fn/2/)

P.S:

I referred to some of the questions which address similar issues, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: you missed the "." for the class in CSS code.check this https://jsfiddle.net/aucex9fn/5/

Comment: Yes, checked it just now, silly mistake.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aucex9fn/6/). Now, first off for you class of `anonymous-customer-header` you forgot the `.` to represent it as a class. Secondly your `margin-top` for it was wrong. That is all updated for you in your fiddle though, but if you would like your CSS it is here:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
#search {
    margin-left: 150px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.anonymous-customer-header {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: "float:right" did make a difference here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your actual css is wrong - but in the fiddle you have missed the . at the start of anonymous-customer-header. However, you have it correct in the css above!

Have a look at this fiddle where it seems to be working correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/aucex9fn/7/

```
.anonymous-customer-header{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```